# split array of first and last names into variables of first and last name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array element in a web template(the size of the array varies per page)
the array has the following format: ['John gray','Matt jones', 'Frank white']. I would like to split the array irrespective of its size into two arrays: one containing the first names: ['John','Matt','Frank'] and one containing the last names: ['gray','jones','white']. I know that for strings you can use a split() method but have not found much on splitting arrays in the manner. any ideas?

Comment: arrays don't need to be split ... but you have an array of strings, which can be split ... `const firstNames = yourArray.map(v => v.split(' ')[0])`

Comment: or, you could do something like `const [firstName, lastName] = yourArray.map(v => v.split(' ')).reduce((r, v) => [[...r[0], v[0]], [...r[1], v[1]]], [[],[]]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to iterate over the array and for each name in the array call the split and save the parts to two different arrays.

```js
let names = ['John gray','Matt jones', 'Frank white'];
let firstNames = [];
let lastNames = [];
names.forEach(name => {
    let splitted = name.split(" ");
    firstNames.push(splitted[0]);
    lastNames.push(splitted[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't "split" arrays, you want to split the array of strings

```js
var array = ['John gray','Matt jones', 'Frank white'];
const [firstNames, lastNames] = array
    .map(v => v.split(' ')) // split each string
    .reduce((r, v) => [[...r[0], v[0]], [...r[1], v[1]]], [[],[]]); // produce an array of arrays, for first and last names
console.log(firstNames, lastNames)
```